# Is it posible to render a 3D model in cesium with compressed textures? (DXT1)

Tags: javascript, 3d, cesiumjs, 3d-model

I am trying to render a 3D model with the cesium javascript library (v1.80). I am rendering a .b3dm model with external textures. It works perfectly when the textures are in the .jpg format, but not when they are compressed with DXT1 to a .dds file. Is compressed textures not supported?

The error I get:

```
A 3D tile failed to load: http://localhost:8080/.../something.b3dm
Cesium.js:1 Error: Failed to load image: http://localhost:8080/.../something_textures.dds
undefined
```

I am certain that the files are found.

Comment: No, sorry, DDS is not supported.

Comment: Thanks! If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As emackey commented on the question, DDS does not seem to be supported by cesium.